# How does locking work in INSERT..ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statements?

Tags: mysql, insert-update, database-deadlocks

I am encountering deadlocks while trying to update multiple rows (a batch) using INSERT..ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. 
Does MySQL lock all the rows in one batch or does it lock only the row it is updating at a point of time?

Comment: May be a better question for http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If autocommit is disabled, then MySql places locks on all touched rows, and releases placed locks on commit. Insert records in consistent order (sort the batch of records by primary key value before inserting) to avoid deadlocks.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MySQL Developer Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

Prior to MySQL 5.6.6, an INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE on a partitioned table using a storage engine such as MyISAM that employs table-level locks locked all partitions of the table. **(This did not and does not occur with tables using storage engines such as InnoDB that employ row-level locking.)** In MySQL 5.6.6 and later, such statements lock only those partitions in which a partitioning key column is updated. See Section 18.6.4, “Partitioning and Locking”, for more information.

I guess `InnoDB` will use index and avoid table level locking(Unless the table is too small that MySQL would use table level locking directly).